# has in the past released oil reserves

Tags: meaning

Does "has in the past..." here mean that Japan has historically released oil reserves, or that Japan used to do so but not anymore? What I'm confused about is the combination of present perfect and "in the past." My understanding of present perfect is that it is used to refer to a past event that is still continuing to the present or has an effect/impact in the present. But I feel like "in the past" has this connotation of "it used to be that way in the past but not anymore." to it, which contradicts what present perfect implies. Could someone explain this to me? Thanks.

> Japan is a member of the International Energy Agency and **has in the
> past** released oil reserves to meet major supply disruptions.
>
> https://www.asahi.com/ajw/articles/15033265

Comment: missing comma: [...] and has, in the past, released oil reserves [...]

Comment: That text is a translation from Japanese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That usage means that there have been some occasions, in the past, when Japan has released oil reserves.
The statement doesn't specify whether they are going to do so again. That depends on the text around that quotation.
The releases of oil reserves are discrete events. "Has released" means that some such events have taken place, and present perfect is appropriate, with no implication that a release is happening now, or will again.

Consider:
*I have taken that bus many times in the past.*
There's no implication there that I will or won't take that bus again.

Comment: Ah I understand now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the *present perfect* gives information *about the present* by referring to a past event.

One of these functions is simply that the event happened in the past, and it's not impossible for it to happen again, but there's no reason to think it will. Another possible function is that because it happened in the past, it's likely to happen again.

In the context you give, the present perfect almost certainly has the latter function, meaning that *Japan is likely to release oil reserves in the future*, which we understand from reading their past behaviour. It may even mean that *Japan can be counted on to release oil*.

There's no reason to believe it's just a statement about the past. *Simple past* would be used to indicate that it no longer happens.

Comment: Your explanation makes it clear to me. Thank you.